# Why do I get parse error on my function name?

Tags: haskell

I've written my code but when I try to compile I get this error: parse error on input `ord'

I'm still learning Haskell, and are starting to get more comfortable with it. I've looked online for an answer, but can't find any that help me with my problem.

```
ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord x:xs = if x == " " then x:(ord s) else
        if x /= " " then x ++ (ord s)
```

I'm quite stuck and can't figure out why I get this error. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Thanks for the help, guys! I've altered my code, but still get the same error...

```
ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord (x:xs) = if x == " " then x:(ord xs) 
            else if x /= " " then x ++ (ord xs)
                else []
```

btw: function is supposed to take in a string, and split the words by the spaces and put them into a table.
F.ex:

> ord "hi my name is annack"
>   should give : ["hi","my","name","is","annack"]

Comment: I get : Oblig1.hs:15:1: error: parse error on input `ord` (ord:: String -> [String] is on line 15

Comment: There are several issues: 1. You need parens around `(x:xs)`, 2. you need an `else` for your last `if`, or probably to not have a second `if` since it only inverts the condition of the first, 3. there is no variable `s`, 4. you're mixing up chars, strings, and string lists. Please consider starting smaller and building out, so that you only have to solve one problem at a time

Comment: Could not reproduce. With the code in your edit, I do not get a parse error. Therefore the problem is almost certainly in a part of the file you are not showing us.

Comment: If the compiler were complaining about a parse error within this code, it would normally point at somewhere in the middle, not at the initial `ord`. Probably the function (or import or whatever) *above* this contains an error. If a previous syntactic structure isn't "closed" properly, and the first thing that the compiler notices to be definitely wrong is your attempt to start the definition of a new function `ord`, then this is the error you'd get. But that means you haven't included the code with the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need parentheses around the pattern matching a non-empty list:

```
ord (x:xs) = ...
```

Once you've fixed this, you have a number of other problems to fix as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I was stuck for a while, but ended up writing new code that was simpler. I did have other functions as well, but they run fine.